# Robotc (c modified) how to pass a char array variable

Tags: c, arrays

My question is is possible to pass array variable in robotc functions?

Here is my attempt:

```
void writeToLog(char  message)
{
    printf("success");
}
char h[10]="";
writeToLog(h)
```

N.B.ROBOTC is a robotics programming language that is a C-Based Programming Language.

Comment: Why don't you refer the manual of _"robotc"_ ? And your question doesn't make sense

Comment: @P0W I did no banana. thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: @P0W Is that a better way of phrasing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with robotc. But in C, it is possible to pass array variable to functions.
You have to change the writeToLog function definition to

```
void writeToLog(char *message) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function actually is getting single `char` as argument and you are attempting to transfer `char*` (pointer to char) to it. Change your prototype declaration to:

```
void writeToLog(char*);
```

And everything will be ok.

Comment: Did you see @A.M.D answer?